# gradle run в Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

Я установила в Eclipse плагин *Eclipse Buildship* (Eclipse Plugin for Gradle) и создала новый gradle-проект. При этом задача *build* успешно выполняется. Но в списке доступных задач во вкладке *Gradle Tasks* нет задачи *run*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить эту задачу и запустить приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выполнения задачи `gradle run` нужно было изменить *build.gradle* файл. После добавления в этот файл строк

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'hello.HelloWorld'
```

задача `gradle run` успешно выполнилась.